# Undecidability of minimal PDAs and TM machines

Tags: formal-languages

Consider
$$L=\{<TM>:TM \text{ is a Turing machine and has minimal states}\}$$
$$L'=\{<PDA>:PDA\text{ is a PDA and has minimal states}\}$$

Which one is recursive?

I think neither $L$ nor $L'$ are  recursive but I can't reduce from a famous problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For all CFL, there is a one-state PDA that recognizes this language. So $L'$ is recursive: you just have to check if the PDA has exactly one state.

For $L$, note that Turing machines with exactly one state can recognize only the empty language or the universal language. That may help to find a reduction (especially knowing that there are two-states universal Turing machines).

Answer (score 3):

This proof is very similar to a proof in [Sipser](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/400716.Introduction_to_the_Theory_of_Computation?ac=1&from_search=true&qid=XwvlSNsyvA&rank=1).
They consider the length of the description $\langle TM \rangle$ instead of the number of states, but the idea is the same.

Assume that $L \in \texttt{RE}$, then there must be an enumerator $E$ enumerating the words of $L$.
Define the TM $A$ such that on word $w$:

- $A$ obtains its own description $\langle A \rangle$ using the recursion theorem,
- runs $E$ until it finds a machine $\langle B \rangle$ with more states than itself, and
- simulates $B$ on $w$.

Thus, $A$ is a machine with less states than $B$ and $L(A) = L(B)$ ↯.
So $L$ can't have been enumerable.