# Is there a one-state PDA that recognizes every context free language?

Tags: context-free, pushdown-automata

[Here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/165657/153411), I read this:

> For all CFL, there is a one-state PDA that recognizes this language.

What is the proof/idea behind this claim?

CFL: Context Free Languages
PDA: Push Down Automaton

Comment: Check [here](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs381/2004fa/onestate.pdf).

Answer (score 6):

We have to be precise.

Each context-free language can be accepted by *empty stack* using a push-down automaton with a single state, or by *final state* and two states. (In the latter case we obviously need one accepting and one non-accepting state.)

The proof uses the equivalence between context-free grammars and push-down automata. Every CFG is equivalent to a PDA with a single state (and empty stack acceptance). Wikipedia mentions the [expand-match](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton#Context-free_languages) construction which directly simulates the context-free derivation on the stack.